# SQL output is not what expect. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || BOWLERLASTNAME
"Bowler Name" , 
 BOWLERADDRESS || ' ' || BOWLERCITY || ' ' || BOWLERSTATE || ' ' || BOWLERZIP 
 "Bowler Address"
 FROM BOWLERS;
```

SQL OUTPUT:

```
 Bowler Name
 ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------

 Bowler Address
 ------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------------
Michael Viescas                                                                 

218 Main Street Redmond WA 98052                                                

Bailey Hallmark                                                                 

Route 2, Box 203B Woodinville WA 98072                                          

Rachel Patterson                                                                

16 Maple Lane Auburn WA 98002                                                   

Bowler Name
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------------
Bowler Address
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------------
Steve Pundt                                                                     

722 Moss Bay Blvd. Kirkland WA 98033                                            

Joe Rosales                                                                     

908 W. Capital Way Tacoma WA 98401
```

32 rows selected

The Output should be:

```
Bowler Name                     Bowler Address
------------------------------  -------------------------

Rachel Patterson                16 Maple Lane Auburn WA 98002
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You mean thw wrapping on the second line?

Comment: I am just wondering why the Bowler name isn't being put into the Bowler name column. It is all getting grouped into the bowler address column.

Comment: How are you executing the SQL?  In command line?  I don't think you are writing anything wrong, but the output looks like command line and it will format it strange.  If you switch to something like MySQL Developer it will return formatted nicely.

Comment: do you want to try something like the below and let us know how it works out?

Comment: select left(some_really_long_column_name,10) as c1,left(another_really_long_column_name,10) as c2 from table

Comment: I am using SQL developer actually haha I have no idea why its being so weird.

Comment: Is it mysql or oracle, I am consfused! :S

Comment: sql>column column_name format a30 maybe?

Comment: oracle sql developer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT (BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || BOWLERLASTNAME) AS "Bowler Name" , 
 (BOWLERADDRESS || ' ' || BOWLERCITY || ' ' || BOWLERSTATE || ' ' || BOWLERZIP) AS "Bowler Address"
 FROM BOWLERS;
```